# Performance with nested data in a script field

Tags: elasticsearch

I am wondering if there is a more performant way of performing a calculation on nested data in a script field or of organizing the data. In the code below, the data will contain values for 50 states and/or other regions. Each user is tied to an area, so the script above will search to see that the `averageValue` in their area is above a certain threshold and return a true/false value for each matching document.

**Mapping**

```
{
  "mydata" : {
    "properties" : {
      ...some fields,
      "related" : {
        "type" : "nested",
        "properties" : {
          "average_value" : {
            "type" : "integer"
          },
          "state" : {
            "type" : "string"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Script**

```
"script_fields" : {
  "inBudget" : {
    "script" : {
      "inline" : "_source.related.find { it.state == default_area && it.average_value >= min_amount } != null",
      "params" : {
        "min_amount" : 100,
        "default_area" : "CA"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I have a working solution using the above method, but it slows my query down and I am curious if there is a better solution. I have been toying with the idea of using a inner object with a key, like: `related_CA` and having each states data in a separate object, however for flexibility I would rather not have to pre-define each region in a mapping (as I may not have them all ahead of time). I feel like I might be missing a simpler/better way and I am open to either reorganizing the data/mapping and/or changes to the script.

Comment: did you find a solution ?

Comment: Unfortunately, not yet. I am working around the issue by executing two queries and correlating them afterwards.